# Unity velocity very unaccurate

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, velocity

I'm learning how to make 2D games in unity through a tutorial, I'm in the animation part its just if statements checking player's velocity and do the right animation acording to that, however even when the player is idle, the y and x velocitys are changing randomly, i know floats arent accurate but the velocity isnt even close to 0

i searched everywhere to an answer and i haven't got anything

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    SpriteRenderer sp;
    Animator anim;
    [SerializeField] float jumpForce = 20f;
    [SerializeField] float moveForce = 15f;
    float dirX;
    private enum MovementState
    {
        Idle, Running, Falling, Jumping
    }
    MovementState state;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sp = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
        dirX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveForce, rb.velocity.y);
        UpdateAnamation();
    }
    private void UpdateAnamation()
    {
        if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.Running;
            sp.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.Running;
            sp.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.Idle;

        }
        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
    }
}
```

---

---

Comment: I don't see your code checking player's velocity, what you checked is the horizontal direction of the input controller. If you search `[unity3d] how to do 2d movement` on this site, you can get a lot of answers.